# Why does runIde task fail in WSL2?

Tags: windows, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, wsl-2

I was created an IntelliJ platform project, my setup is :

- gradle -> 7.2
- Groovy -> 3.0.8
- java jdk -> openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
- intelliJ -> 2021.2.1 (Ultimate Edition)
- org.jetbrains.intellij pluging -> 1.2.0

The fail message is:

```
Execution failed for task ':runIde'.
> Process 'command '/home/boyscout/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains/jbre/jbr_jcef-11_0_11-linux-x64-b1504.16/extracted/jbr/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Unable to list file systems to check whether they can be watched. The whole state of the virtual file system has been discarded. Reason: Could not query file systems: could not open mount file (errno 2: No such file or directory)
```

**With the same setup when I launch the build on Windows, it's not failed.**

I think the problem is from WSL but I don't know the reason.

This my IntelliJ settings :
[gradle settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DOS3.png)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Solved problem.
I restarted Wsl from services.msc, found LXSSMANAGER, right-click it and restart service.

Comment: The same error message exists on Bitbucket pipeline (a docker container), which isn't WSL2... there at least it only happens after the build has completed (`:runIde` doesn't apply there). The mere question would be, what it even tries to mount?